# How to delete the extra sections of IP on Scarpy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

When you run the following code on Google:

```
response.ip_address
```

Her values equal to:

```
IPv4Address('79.127.127.87')
```

Screenshot:

[image]

But the expected answer is as follows:

```
'79.127.127.87'
```

How to get this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use str():

```py
scrapy shell

In [1]: url='https://httpbin.org/'

In [2]: req = scrapy.Request(url=url)

In [3]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://httpbin.org/> (referer: None)

In [4]: str(response.ip_address)
Out[4]: '3.93.133.228'
```

Comment: Is it possible to help me with this question? Your mastery is great. https://stackoverflow.com/q/73347370/8519380

Answer (score 1):

As you not mentioned `complete code` , I'm suggesting this method...Have you tried post processing?

```
import re
ip = """(IPv4Address('79.127.127.87')"""

out = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", ip, re.DOTALL)
#print(out)
#print(type(out))

ip_final = s = ''.join(out)
print(ip_final)
```

output

```
79.127.127.87
```

Comment: I have a better way to do this: split("'") but I'm going to do it with Scrapy.

Comment: can i get complete Scrapy code...Like from importing to printing `ip` so that I can see inside module if any direct functions are available