# scrapy get tag a attribute values of rel

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

types of tags a:

```
<a rel="sponsored" href="https://cheese.example.com/Appenzeller_cheese">Appenzeller</a>
```

or

```
<a rel="ugc" href="https://cheese.example.com/Appenzeller_cheese">Appenzeller</a>
```

and one or more of the following values:

```
rel="sponsored"
or
rel="ugc"
or
rel="ugc nofollow noreferrer"
```

Apparently, Scrapy only supports the following value (Just "nofollow"):

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://cheese.example.com/Appenzeller_cheese">Appenzeller</a>
```

How can I get other values (like: ugc, noreferrer and ... ) with the help of [Link Extractors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html)?

Comment: Good question.  From what I can tell it appears you would have to write your own linkextractor

Comment: @Alexander I found a resource and it might help, but I don't know how to use it. Do you know?
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/aa31811cfdc85eda07ddab25178d5003155523ec

Comment: @Sardar do you want to get the attribute from the [Link](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.link) object, or do you want the link extractor to return it instead of the url?

Comment: @sardar I have already looked into it.  You would need to rewrite the link extractor.  It would be easier to just parse the responses for links yourself and extract the rel manually using scrapy selectors

Comment: @SuperUser I want to get all attribute values from rel

Comment: @Alexander I don't think it's that simple.
Relative links can be difficult to calculate whether it is internal or external. <a href="/about_team.htm" rel"nofollow noreferrer">text</a>

Comment: for relative links you can just use the `response.urljoin(extracted_link)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the `from lxml import etree` library.

You can't do this with Link Extractors.

Like: `etree.fromstring(tag)`